# jquery ajax success not showing data

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a simple form that passes values to php using serialize. Now what I am trying to do is, when the values are passed to php for processing, display a message to the user based on wether there is any data or if the values are empty. I can get the message to display by not doing the checks and having just echo value say 1 for success. Is there a way to display the echo of the php to the user using my code. Thanks

```
data: send,
      success: function (data) {
      if (data == ''){
      $('#brtv-result').addClass("result_msg").html(data).show(1000).delay(4000).fadeOut(3000);
      }


if(empty($service) {

echo 'You must select a service level';
}

else
if ($department == "Choose Department"} {

echo 'Please select a department';
}

else
if (empty($authorised)) {

echo 'You must enter an authorised name';
}

else
if ($address == "Choose Address") {

echo 'Please select a retireval address';
}

else
if (empty($boxnumber)) {

echo 'You must enter a box number to retrieve';
}
else
{
echo $boxnumber;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check if `data` is **not** empty.

```
if (data != ''){
      $('#brtv-result').addClass("result_msg").html(data).show(1000).delay(4000).fadeOut(3000);
}
```

And there is a missing `)` in your PHP code:

```
if(empty($service)) { // ...
```

Comment: martin problem is that displays the errors ok but when the result is valid it doesn't run the else statement. else
      {
      //location.reload(true);
      $('#brtv-result').addClass("result_msg").html("You have successfully retrieved: "+data); }

Comment: Then I would recommend to use JSON. With that you can send "objects" from PHP to Javascript. Then you could check if(data.error) and display data.errorMessage or data.retrievedData. Look at: http://ditio.net/2008/07/17/php-json-and-javascript-usage/

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are displaying your output only if the response from your ajax call is an empty string:

change

```
if (data == '') {
```

to something else that makes sense for your logic. It appears that you output something no matter what in your php script so maybe parse the response into an integer and make sure it's greater than zero (or something like that):

```
var tmp = parseInt(data);
if (data > 0) {
```

Comment: jasper. could you please provide example becuase I tried your answer and it just reloads the page. thanks.  success: function (data) {
      var tmp = parseInt(data);
      if (data > 0){
      $('#brtv-result').addClass("result_msg").html(data).show(1000).delay(1000).fadeOut(1000);
      }